# Error: timed out while waiting for target halted

Tags: lattice, openocd

trying to debugging project OpenOCD on Lattice Crosslink-NX device, but I'm catch an error:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-01214-g0ace94f-dirty (2021-10-28-14:20)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
0
1
FTUSB-0
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
none separate
Warn : Transport "jtag" was already selected
adapter speed: 4000 kHz
C:\Users\ASPOD\hw\HW/src/cpu0.yaml
Warn : Interface already configured, ignoring
adapter speed: 4000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 260
jtag_ntrst_delay: 250
Info : set servers polling period to 50ms
QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
Device List: 
    LIFCL-40-ES:0x#device_num
Info : clock speed 4000 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: fpga_spinal.bridge tap/device found: 0x#device_num (mfg: 0x7ff (<invalid>), part: 0x0001, ver: 0x1)
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Started by GNU MCU Eclipse
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Info : Halt timed out, wake up GDB.
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted


Info : JTAG tap: fpga_spinal.bridge tap/device found: 0x#device_num (mfg: 0x7ff (<invalid>), part: 0x0001, ver: 0x1)
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted
TARGET: fpga_spinal.cpu0 - Not halted


Info : Halt timed out, wake up GDB.
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted

Info : JTAG tap: fpga_spinal.bridge tap/device found: 0x#device_num (mfg: 0x7ff (<invalid>), part: 0x0001, ver: 0x1)
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted
TARGET: fpga_spinal.cpu0 - Not halted


Info : Halt timed out, wake up GDB.
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted

Assertion failed!

Program: C:\lscc\propel\2.1\sdk\openocd\bin\openocd.exe
File: src/target/vexriscv.c, Line 1142

Expression: target->state == TARGET_HALTED
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: There is not enough information to fix it. For all what we know, you might have a bad programming cable or just forgot to apply power somewhere.

Comment: You might want to address the warnings as well.

Comment: were you able to figure out what the problem was? I have exactly the same errors and I'm not understanding what they are due to. Thank you very much

Comment: @Antonino sorry, I may have been able to figure it, but I don't remember anymore... Good luck